# how to customize slack payload

Tags: shell-script, curl

I'm trying to integrate slack with one of my shell script. I have different conditions, for which the Message part of payload is different.

My script will look like

```
#!/bin/bash

SLACK_URL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/******
CHANNEL="#channel"
PAYLOAD="'payload={\"channel\": \"${SLACK_CHANNEL}\", \"username\": \"${USER}\", \"text\": \"$MESSAGE\", \"icon_emoji\": \":slack:\"}"
```

Case 1:
  condition :

```
 curl -s -S -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACK_URL
```

Case 2:
  condition

```
  curl -s -S -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACK_URL
```

Case 3:
  condition

```
  curl -s -S -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACK_URL
```

In each case my Message should be different. I'm trying to avoid declaring payload each time with custom message, looking for an option where I can parse my custom message to my payload. Help please.

Comment: Why are all 3 of your "case N: condition" commands exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can build up your `$PAYLOAD` piece by piece based on your conditions:

```
PAYLOAD="payload={"
PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD\"channel\": \"${SLACK_CHANNEL}\","
PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD\"username\": \"${USER}\","

case $MESSAGE_TYPE in
    1)
        PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD \"text\": \"$MESSAGE1\","
        ;;
    2)
        PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD \"text\": \"$MESSAGE2\","
        ;;
    3)
        PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD \"text\": \"$MESSAGE3\","
        ;;
esac

PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD \"icon_emoji\": \":slack:\""
PAYLOAD="$PAYLOAD}"

curl -s -S -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACK_URL
```

Alternatively you could have Bash lazily evaluate `$PAYLOAD` with `eval` once you've set `$MESSAGE` correctly.

```
PAYLOAD_PATTERN='payload={\"channel\": \"${SLACK_CHANNEL}\", \"username\": \"${USER}\", \"text\": \"$MESSAGE\", \"icon_emoji\": \":slack:\"}'
MESSAGE=...
eval "PAYLOAD=\"$PAYLOAD_PATTERN\""

curl -s -S -X POST --data-urlencode "$PAYLOAD" $SLACK_URL
```

This is a common pattern in shell programming. Note however, that if you any part of the variables expanded as part of `$PAYLOAD_PATTERN` include untrusted input, using `eval` in this manner could lead to security problems as an adversary that has the ability to influence any piece of the input arbitrary may use this to gain arbitrary code execution capabilities on the system executing the script.